# Reading Excel File using C# (Want everything as string)

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I am reading an excel file using C# code into a data-table and displaying it into WPF data-grid. When I am reading dates from excel file and display them into data-grid the format of dates changes. I am using Oledb ADO.NET to read excel file.

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

So basically I want to read data from excel, they it appears to user when he/she opens an excel and the same way I want to display it in my data-grid. Please guide me. If  you need any other information about this problem, please ask me.

Regards,
Priyank Thakkar

Comment: Could you provide connction string that you are using for Oledb?

Answer (score 1):

Use a connection string similar to this:

```
OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

As quoted from [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel):

> "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers,
>   dates, strings etc) data columns as text. Note that this option might
>   affect excel sheet write access negative.

Comment: Also target the x86 platform, as the Jet drivers will not run in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the file as a .csv and:

```
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("path\file.csv");

        foreach (string s in fileLines)
        {
            string[] splitRow = s.Split(',');
            //do stuff w/ row columns
        }
```